# SQLite Android query

Tags: java, android, sql, android-sqlite

I'm having troubles with this query which doesn't seems to work. 
Can not figure it out. Is it a problem with this method ? 
I have manually entered one account before and checked that the database is not empty. 
Cursor getCount method return 0 systematically.

```
private static final int VERSION_BDD = 1;
private static final String NOM_BDD = "account.db";
private static final String TABLE_ACCOUNT = "table_account";
private static final String COL_EMAIL = "Email";
private static final String COL_PASSWORD = "Password";

...
...

public Account getAccountWithEmail(String email){
     Cursor c = bdd.rawQuery("select * from table_account where Email = '" + email + "'", null);
     return cursorToAccount(c);
}

private Account cursorToAccount(Cursor c){
    if (c.getCount() == 0){
        return null;
    }

    else{
        c.moveToFirst();
        Account account = new Account();
        account.setEmail(c.getString(NUM_COL_EMAIL));
        account.setPassword(c.getString(NUM_COL_PASSWORD));
        c.close();

        return account;
    }
}
```

Comment: Read the documentation for how rawQuery method works. Youll find your answer there.

Comment: Provide cursorToAccount method.

Comment: Done, but I think the problem really comes from the query

Comment: Let me know if the below answer works for you.. it should

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to:

```
public Account getAccountWithEmail(String email){
    Cursor c = bdd.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_ACCOUNT + " WHERE " + COL_EMAIL "= ?", new String[]{email});
    return cursorToAccount(c);
}
```

read this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery(java.lang.String, java.lang.String[])

> selectionArgs You may include ?s in where clause in the query, which
>   will be replaced by the values from selectionArgs. The values will be
>   bound as Strings.

You should use your static variables for those various column names and table names, as it is just better practice (avoid typos!). As for the query, you want to use the selectionArgs and use of ? which corresponds to the arrays index for each argument

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it worked but for text without '@' character like e-mail address. But the query seems to work. I'll change my account definition with a username and not with e-mail address.
PS : You forgot a "+" just after "COL_EMAIL", Thanks